# ascx files not recognizing System.web.ui.webcontrol namespace

Tags: vb.net

I have forked a project that was handed to me.

In a single solution, I created a new vb.net web application and copied folders over one by one. The intent was to isolate an issue that I have not been able to track down.

I have encountered an odd behaviour, thought someone else might have run across this. There is a folder of user controls (ascx files) and many of them have GridViews in them. (ImageButtons also cause the problem).

The source project is fine w/ it. It does compile. 
The copied project refuses to recognize  System.Web.UI.WebControls.

After checking all the references, and the included Assemblies in each project, I created a blank web page and added a GridView. It works fine.

So I took the first bad webcontrol(documentGrid), 
* created a new webcontrol in the same folder called documentGrid1
* copied the html over 
* copied the logic over 
* visually inspected the designer file
* deleted documentGrid and renamed documentGrid1 --> documentGrid.

It works fine. 
I tried it again and used winMerge to compare all 3 files before deleting them. 
Perfect matches, new one works, old one doesnt.

Is there possibly somewhere in one of the support files that may have problems since I copied it from one project to another?

There are about 40 of these, I will proceed with the work around, but there has to be a reason these are failing.

As a final clue, 
In the old files, I can type

```
dim x as new system.web.
```

And I will get 3 choices... 
AppNetHostingPermission
AppNetHostingPermissionLevel
AppNetHostingPermissionAttribute

if i type the same thing in the newly created usercontrols, I get a myriad of options, including the UI namespace, which is where the solution lies.

I have verified the file extensions are all as expected 
.ascx
.ascx.designer.vb
.ascx.vb

There must be some other place that is controlling these? 
What am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

all the files showed as INCLUDED (which is why they were producing errors)

I eventually tried EXCLUDING , then INCLUDING a single file.

That fixed it.

So I then and EXCLUDED and INCLUDED all the remaining (shift click allows you to do multiple files at a time)

This resolved the issue.